# Time complexity of Sorting list of Tuples based on second value

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples, key

so I wanted to know what will be the time complexity of sorted function if we use a key to it , I know it is nlogn for sorting normally but will it be same for following case:

```
a=[[(1, 4,),1], [(2, 4), 10], [(1, 3), 11], [(2, 3), 5], [(3, 4), 7]]

a=sorted(a, key = lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
```

So here I sorted the list based on the second element so will the time complexity remain same i.e nlogn or will it differ

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would change. However if getting the key was some expensive function to compute it might be a different story. Either way, attempting to optimize this probably isn't worth it. Generally you can assume provided functions are implemented in the best way possible unless told otherwise. Plus Python is aimed at ease of use and flexibility. Speed is sometimes the price you have pay for these features.

Comment: Python's `sorted()` works on `timsort`, which has the worst case complexity of `nlogn` and the best case `n`. In your case the time complexity will remain the same as above. You are just asking to sort the list of keys, which is same as sorting a list.

Comment: @Locke ",attempting to optimize this probably isn't worth it"- Well said!

Comment: @Solen'ya got  i thought the key function would also take some time but i guess wouldn't  and i just saw instead of key we could also use itemgetter from operator module that is does it in even less time.

Answer (score 0):

Time Complexity of the below is definitely nlog2(n).
Note that it is base 2, not base 10.

```
a=[[(1, 4,),1], [(2, 4), 10], [(1, 3), 11], [(2, 3), 5], [(3, 4), 7]]
a=sorted(a, key = lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
```

The Timsort algorithm, which the sorted function uses, is considered a hybrid sorting algorithm because it combines the Insertion Sort and Merge Sort together.